# Pynput Key entering loop skipping enter commands

Tags: python, pynput

I am trying to write a python script that automatically types shipment details using Pynput. For some reason my code works perfectly for the first iteration, but starts skipping the enter commands on later iterations. The function being called is:

```
def enter_order():
   print("STARTING IN 5...")
   time.sleep(1)
   print("4...")
   time.sleep(1)
   print("3...")
   time.sleep(1)
   print("2...")
   time.sleep(1)
   print("1...")
   time.sleep(1)
   for i in range(3):
      keyboard.type("DATE")
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.press(Key.enter)
      keyboard.release(Key.enter)
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.type("FO")
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.press(Key.enter)
      keyboard.release(Key.enter)
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.type("SHIPMENT")
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.press(Key.enter)
      keyboard.release(Key.enter)
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.type("EDI")
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.press(Key.enter)
      keyboard.release(Key.enter)
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.type("NRM")
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.press(Key.enter)
      keyboard.release(Key.enter)
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.type("SEQUENCE")
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.press(Key.enter)
      keyboard.release(Key.enter)
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.type("FW")
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.press(Key.enter)
      keyboard.release(Key.enter)
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.type("AUTOTYPE")
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.press(Key.enter)
      keyboard.release(Key.enter)
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.type("CONSUMPTION")
      time.sleep(1)
      keyboard.press(Key.enter)
      keyboard.release(Key.enter)
      keyboard.press(Key.enter)
      keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

The output i'm getting looks like this:

```
DATE
FO
SHIPMENT
EDI
NRM
SEQUENCE
FW
AUTOTYPE
CONSUMPTION

DATEFO
SHIPMENTEDI
NRMSEQUENCE
FWAUTOTYPE
CONSUMPTION
DATEFOSHIPMENT
EDINRM
SEQUENCEFW
AUTOTYPECONSUMPTION
```

Not sure where i'm going wrong here, and any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce the error. I used the same code you provided with the addition on defining the `keyboard = Controller()` but I guess you might be doing it at another place in your code.

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

def enter_order():
    print("STARTING IN 5...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("4...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("3...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("2...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("1...")
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard = Controller()
    for i in range(3):
        keyboard.type("DATE")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.type("FO")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.type("SHIPMENT")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.type("EDI")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.type("NRM")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.type("SEQUENCE")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.type("FW")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.type("AUTOTYPE")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.type("CONSUMPTION")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)


enter_order()
```

[image: snapshot-of-output]